# Why is the ternary operator used to define 1 and 0 in a macro?

Tags: c++, c, boolean, ternary-operator

I'm using an SDK for an embedded project. In this source code I found some code which at least I found peculiar. In many places in the SDK there is source code in this format:

```
#define ATCI_IS_LOWER( alpha_char )  ( ( (alpha_char >= ATCI_char_a) && (alpha_char <= ATCI_char_z) ) ? 1 : 0 )

#define ATCI_IS_UPPER( alpha_char )  ( ( (alpha_char >= ATCI_CHAR_A) && (alpha_char <= ATCI_CHAR_Z) ) ? 1 : 0 )
```

Does the use of the ternary operator here make any difference?

Isn't

```
#define FOO (1 > 0)
```

the same as

```
#define BAR ( (1 > 0) ? 1 : 0)
```

?

I tried evaluating it by using

```
printf("%d", FOO == BAR);
```

and get the result 1, so it seems that they are equal. Is there a reason to write the code like they did?

Comment: No, there is no reason. You are right.

Comment: "They" do not appear to have used a ternary operator, based on your question.

Comment: The smart way would be to write `(int)(something >> x) // ensure integer even in C++`. As a rule of thumb, don't write strange code without leaving a comment about why.

Comment: Partially off-topic: When does the madness of using the preprocessor stop? There is potential multiple evaluation of functions involved here. Just unnecessary.

Comment: Sometimes it's nice to be explicit, too. The ternary operator here makes it clear at a glance that the purpose of the macro is to return a boolean.

Comment: @Art: Not really.

Comment: @Lundin: But it's not strange code, it's perfectly obvious - at least to any competent C programmer - that it's returning a logical true/false value depending on whether or not the argument is upper/lower case.

Comment: At the very least, the macros should use `(alpha_char)` instead of `alpha_char`, just to make sure it doesn't break [if someone tries something crazy like `ATCI_IS_LOWER(true || -1)`](http://ideone.com/aZKneD).

Comment: Looks like the kind of C I wrote long ago.
I'd come to C from Pascal, which had a dedicated `boolean` type, so I wasted untold time changing horrors like `if (n)` to `if (0 != n)`, probably adding a dubious cast "to make sure".
I'm sure I bullet-proofed inequalities like `if (a < b) ...`, too.
Sure it _looked_ like Pascal's `if a < b then ...`, but I knew that _C's_ `<` wasn't a `boolean` but an `int`, and an `int` could be _almost anything_!
Fear leads to gold-plating, gold-plating leads to paranoia, paranoia leads to... code like that.

Comment: @jamesqf Implicit portability to C++ is not perfectly obvious to a C programmer, no...

Comment: @Lundin: But where does the question of C++ portability arise?  The OP says it's an embedded SDK, and uses printf rather than cout in the example, so I'm guessing it's C code, no?

Comment: @jamesqf Logical/comparative operators in C return `int` of value 1/0, but they return `bool` of value true/false in C++. The only sense this code does is to ensure `int` even in C++. Alternatively, the programmer didn't know what they were doing, which is also a likely explanation. In pure C, this code makes as little sense as `1 ? 1 : 0`.

Comment: @Lundin: I really don't understand where you're coming from at all.  To me, they seem like perfectly understandable ways to do tests for upper and lower case, returning a logical TRUE/FALSE value.  Since it's an embedded SDK, I assume standard lib functions aren't available.  And if you care to look at the definitions of the GCC islower & isupper functions (in ctype.h), these are much simpler.

Comment: @jamesqf My point is that this macro can be written as `#define ATCI_IS_LOWER( alpha_char )  ( (alpha_char) >= ATCI_char_a && (alpha_char) <= ATCI_char_z )` This gives a result of `1` or `0`. No need for the `?:` garbage at the end. (I also fixed the severe macro operator precedence bugs that the original code suffered from.)

Comment: @Lundin: Sure, you can do that, but to me the intent seems less clear.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You are correct, in C it is tautologous. Both your particular ternary conditional *and* `(1 > 0)` are of type `int`.

But it *would* matter in C++ though, in some curious corner cases (e.g. as parameters to overloaded functions), since your ternary conditional expression is of type `int`, whereas `(1 > 0)` is of type `bool`.

My guess is that the author has put some thought into this, with an eye to preserving C++ compatibility.

Comment: I thought `bool <-> int` conversions are implicit in C++ by §4.7/4 from the standard (integral conversion), so how would it matter?

Comment: Consider two overloads of a function `foo`, one taking a `const bool&` the other taking a `const int&`. One of them pays you, the other reformats your  hard disk. You might want to make sure you're calling the correct overload in that case.

Comment: wouldn't it be more obvious to handle this case by casting the result to `int` rather than by using the ternary?

Comment: @Bathsheba While a legitimate corner case, any programmer who uses integral overloads to implement such inconsistent behavior is fully evil.

Comment: @Motun: Equivalence and equality are not the same thing, and sometimes we care about one or the other.

Comment: @martinkunev It may be more obvious to you, in which case, if *you* had written the code, that's what would have been done, I suppose.

Comment: @JAB: You don't have to be evil, you just have to make the (common) mistake of writing a piece of code that accidentally does two different things (or worse, invoke _undefined behavior_) depending on integral type, and have the misfortune of doing so in a place that can trigger radically different code paths.

Comment: "the author has put some thought into this" but didn't take a few seconds to write it down in a comment :(

Answer (score 28):

There are linting tools that are of the opinion that the result of a comparison is boolean, and can't be used directly in arithmetic.

Not to name names or point any fingers, but [PC-lint is such a linting tool](http://www.gimpel.com/html/bugs/bug514a.htm).

I'm not saying they're right, but it's a possible explanation to why the code was written like that.

Comment: `Not to name names or point any fingers,` but you sort of did both, lol.

Answer (score 19):

You'll sometimes see this in *very old* code, from before there was a C standard to spell out that `(x > y)` evaluates to numeric 1 or 0; some CPUs would rather make that evaluate to −1 or 0 instead, and some *very old* compilers may have just followed along, so some programmers felt they needed the extra defensiveness.

You'll sometimes also see this because *similar* expressions *don't* necessarily evaluate to numeric 1 or 0.  For instance, in

```
#define GRENFELZ_P(flags) (((flags) & F_DO_GRENFELZ) ? 1 : 0)
```

the inner `&`-expression evaluates to either 0 or the numeric value of `F_DO_GRENFELZ`, which is probably *not* 1, so the `? 1 : 0` serves to canonicalize it.  I personally think it's clearer to write that as

```
#define GRENFELZ_P(flags) (((flags) & F_DO_GRENFELZ) != 0)
```

but reasonable people can disagree.  If you had a whole bunch of these in a row, testing different kinds of expressions, someone might've decided that it was more maintainable to put `? 1 : 0` on the end of *all* of them than to worry about which ones actually needed it.

Comment: On the whole I prefer to use `!!( expr )` to canonicalise a boolean, but I will admit that it is confusing if you are not familiar with it.

Comment: @PJTraill Every time you put spaces on the inside of your parentheses, God kills a kitten.  Please.  Think of the kittens.

Comment: That is the best reason I have heard not to put spaces inside brackets in a C programme.

Answer (score 15):

There's a bug in the SDK code, and the ternary was probably a kludge to fix it.

Being a macro the arguments (alpha_char) can be any expression and should be parenthesized because expressions such as 'A' && 'c' will fail the test.

```
#define IS_LOWER( x ) ( ( (x >= 'a') && (x <= 'z') ) ?  1 : 0 )
std::cout << IS_LOWER('A' && 'c');
**1**
std::cout << IS_LOWER('c' && 'A');
**0**
```

This is why one should always parenthesize macro arguments in the expansion.

So in your example (but with parameters), these are both bugged.

```
#define FOO(x) (x > 0)
#define BAR(x) ((x > 0) ? 1 : 0)
```

They would most correctly be replaced by

```
#define BIM(x) ((x) > 0)
```

@CiaPan Makes a great point in following comment which is that using a parameter more than once leads to undefinable results. For instance

```
#define IS_LOWER( x ) (((x) >= 'a') && ((x) <= 'z'))
char ch = 'y';
std::cout << IS_LOWER(ch++);
**1** 
**BUT ch is now '{'**
```

Comment: Another bug is that the parameter is used twice, so an argument with side effects will lead to unpredictable results: `IS_LOWER(++ var)` may increment `var` once or twice, additionally it may not notice and recognize lower-case `'z'` if `var` was `'y'` before the macro call. That's why such macros should be avoided, or just forward the argument to a function.

Answer (score 5):

In C it doesn't matter.
Boolean expressions in C have type `int` and a value that's either `0` or `1`, so

```
ConditionalExpr ? 1 : 0
```

has no effect.

In C++, it's effectively a cast to `int`, because conditional expressions in C++ have type `bool`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#ifndef __cplusplus

#define print_type(X) _Generic(X, int: puts("int"), bool: puts("bool") );

#else
template<class T>
int print_type(T const& x);
template<> int print_type<>(int const& x) { return puts("int"); }
template<> int print_type<>(bool const& x) { return puts("bool"); }


#endif

int main()
{
    print_type(1);
    print_type(1 > 0);
    print_type(1 > 0 ? 1 : 0);

/*c++ output:
  int 
  int 
  int

  cc output:
  int
  bool
  int
*/

}
```

It's also possible no effect was intended, and the author simply thought it made the code clearer.

Comment: BTW, I think C should follow suite and make boolean expressions `_Bool`, now that C has `_Bool` and `_Generic`. It shouldn't break much code given that all smaller types autopromote to `int` in most contexts anyway.

Answer (score 5):

One simple explanation is that some people either don't understand that a condition would return the same value in C, or they think that it is cleaner to write `((a>b)?1:0)`.

That explains why some also use similar constructs in languages with proper booleans, which in C-syntax would be `(a>b)?true:false)`.

This also explains why you shouldn't needlessly change this macro.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, being an embedded software, would give some clues. Maybe there are many macros written using this style, to easy hint that ACTI lines use direct logic rather than Inverted logic.